# generate selected number of text fields in php

Tags: php, html, textfield

Nowadays I'm doing web project for my university mini-project. I'm building a Quizzes management site. User logged on my site I need supply to the user to facilitate for create a quiz. The user can select how many questions include his quiz. But today I have a problem. How to do this?

I create sample code below. First form supply to the user, User can select the number of questions in the quiz.

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <form action='questions.php'>
   <select name="dob-day" id="dob-day">
      <option value="">-----</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
   </select>
   <input type=submit value='Submit'>
</form>
</body
</html>
```

Then after my site should generate a selected number of text fields for questions.

ex: If user select 2 questions for this quiz,

Then my site supply 2 text fields for entering questions with multiple answers.
(This is not a PHP code. This only sample code for describing my problem to you.)

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<!--start: Wrapper-->
 <div id="wrapper">  
  <!--start: Container -->
     <div class="container">
        <!-- start: Row -->
        <div class="row">
   <h3>Enter the question for quiz.</h3>
   <br>
   <div class="input">
   <table>
   <tr>
    <td>Q1)</td>
    <td><textarea tabindex="3" id="message" class="input-xxlarge" name="body" rows="2"></textarea></td>
    
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>A)</td>
    <td><textarea tabindex="3" id="message" class="input-xxlarge" name="body" rows="1"></textarea></td>
    <td>B)</td>
    <td><textarea tabindex="3" id="message" class="input-xxlarge" name="body" rows="1"></textarea></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>C)</td>
    <td><textarea tabindex="3" id="message" class="input-xxlarge" name="body" rows="1"></textarea></td>
    <td>D)</td>
    <td><textarea tabindex="3" id="message" class="input-xxlarge" name="body" rows="1"></textarea></td>
   </tr>
   <tr><td colspan="5"><hr width="1150px"><br><br></td></tr>
   </table>
   <table>
   <tr>
    <td>Q2)</td>
    <td><textarea tabindex="3" id="message" class="input-xxlarge" name="body" rows="2"></textarea></td>
    
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>A)</td>
    <td><textarea tabindex="3" id="message" class="input-xxlarge" name="body" rows="1"></textarea></td>
    <td>B)</td>
    <td><textarea tabindex="3" id="message" class="input-xxlarge" name="body" rows="1"></textarea></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>C)</td>
    <td><textarea tabindex="3" id="message" class="input-xxlarge" name="body" rows="1"></textarea></td>
    <td>D)</td>
    <td><textarea tabindex="3" id="message" class="input-xxlarge" name="body" rows="1"></textarea></td>
   </tr>
   <tr><td colspan="5"><hr width="1150px"><br><br></td></tr>
   </table>
            </div>
        </div>
   <!-- end: Row -->       
  </div>
  <!--end: Container-->    
 </div>
 <!-- end: Wrapper  --> 
    </body
</html
```

I think, doing my task to use PHP language. Can I use PHP to get the solution for this?

What can I do?
please anyone can help me with this problem.

Thank for any audience.

Comment: Hi, can you post your so we can help you ?

Comment: Include your research on what you have done in the post.

Comment: Can i use php for get solution for this?

Comment: Yes, if you want to render the page in php you can.

Comment: Include your html for the questions form and I'll plug it into a php script if I still have enough time.

Comment: @Aunt Jamaima can you give me sample code for solve my problem.

Comment: I sort of posted something below, but if you need more help beyond that you'll want to include the sample html that you want to use to render your questions on the form that says "Enter the question for the quiz"

Comment: @sameeralakshitha. Have you done a hello world tutorial for php yet?

Comment: @Aunt Jamaima now i edited my post. You can easy to answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes php can do this sort of work. Personally I only enable javascript on an 'as needed' basis.

The following is incomplete, but should get you started. Remember that you'll have to have something to execute the php. Php is not rendered in the browser. I use wamp on my windows development machine.

First page

```
<form action='questions.php'>
   <select name="numberOfQuestions" id="dob-day">
      <option value="">-----</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="20">20</option>
      <option value="25">25</option>
      <option value="40">40</option>
   </select>
   <input type=submit value='Submit'>
</form>
```

questions.php:

```
<?php
   for($x=1;$x<=$_GET['numberOfQuestions'];$x++){
?>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Q<?=$x?>)</td>
            <td><textarea tabindex="3" id="message" class="input-xxlarge" name="question<?=$x?>" rows="2"></textarea></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A)</td>
            <td><textarea tabindex="3" id="message" class="input-xxlarge" name="answer<?=$x?>A" rows="1"></textarea></td>
            <td>B)</td>
            <td><textarea tabindex="3" id="message" class="input-xxlarge" name="answer<?=$x?>B" rows="1"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>C)</td>
            <td><textarea tabindex="3" id="message" class="input-xxlarge" name="answer<?=$x?>C" rows="1"></textarea></td>
            <td>D)</td>
            <td><textarea tabindex="3" id="message" class="input-xxlarge" name="answer<?=$x?>D" rows="1"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="5"><hr width="1150px"><br><br></td></tr>
        </table>
<?php
   }
?>
```

Please note, you'll want a different naming convention for the questions your users create than naming them all 'body', which would make it impossible for you to distinguish between the inputs when you capture the questions and answers created by the user.

Comment: Well, that downvote you had sure wasn't mine and sure beats a "comment" any day. So, I'll upvote, that looks OK to me.

Comment: The only thing though @AuntJamaima is that you may have gotten that downvote for any given reason. One could be answering to a broad/unclear question, or the GET array you used doesn't match the name attribute for the form's element. That should be edited/fixed.

Comment: @Aunt Jamaima I checked your answer but I came a error.

Comment: Thanks Fred and Halfer. I think you're right that it's best not to answer a ridiculously vague question.

Comment: @Aunt Jamaima my php error was Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\questions.php on line 2

Comment: The value inside the $_GET has to match the name of the input on the form that makes the post.

Comment: @Aunt Jamaima Finally I can solved my problem. Thank you very much spent your time for me. your answer will help for success my university project. Thanks..